# tap on TextField reseting the view position

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, textfield

Here is my problem:
I have a first form that needs to be completed, once completed you can access the second form, it's an UIView that slide from the left to my view.

At the moment when I tap on one of the text fields of the second form, the position of the view got reseted and I have a view on the first form again.

Here is my code for sliding:

```
@IBAction func Postulate(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView .animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.formView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 414, 736)
    })
}
```

How can tapping on a textfield reset the view ? And how can I counter it ?

I tried to reslide the view with a duration of 0 when a textfield is tapped but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I found a hack to bypass this.
I started the position of my second form view at 0 (on the view) and with the hidden state set as true. Then I make it slide to the left out of screen (being hidden) like this:

```
    formView.hidden = true;
    UIView .animateWithDuration(0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.formView.frame = CGRectMake(-425, 64, 414, 736)
    })
```

When the button to go on my form view is pressed I put my form view hidden state to false and I make it slide to the right so the user can see it.
When I tap on the field, the position reset, but because the form view position was created in the view, it doesn't change.

Finally, when I click on my "return" button from the form view, I make it slide back to the left and make it's hidden state to true. With so on, when the user want to change anything on the first form, the positions are reseted, but the hidden state allow the user to see the form he wants to see and not the other.

Hope I helped someone.
THIS IS JUST A SWIFT HACK, this work, but it's probably not the best solution, if you have a better solution, give it so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set the VC to be textField delegate then use the delegate method, textFieldBeganEditing or something like that to recognize when user tap on the text field.

```
class ClassName:UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet week var textField: UITextField! {
        didSet { textField.delegate = self }
    }
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField){
        //user tapped on the textField, do what you wanna do here
    }
}
```

Comment: there might be some typos in the code, I wrote it right here